# <input type="email"> バリデーションエラーの言語設定

Tags: html5

ブラウザによりますが、メールアドレス入力欄にて
@がなかったり、＠以降がなかったりすると
エラーが表示されますが、

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="email" name="mailaddress">
      <input type="submit" value="送信">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

そのエラー文の言語を任意に設定することはできますでしょうか。

Comment: [仕様](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html)にそれらしいものはないですね。ブラウザの言語設定あるいはhtmlの`lang`属性で変わるのかもしれませんが検証してません。いずれにしても、そもそもこの機能がブラウザに依存するので、確実に用意したいならjavascriptなどで自分で実装するしかないと思います。

Answer (score 2):

> これらのメッセージの外見やテキストを変更するには、JavaScript を使用しなければなりません。HTML や CSS だけで変更する方法はありません。
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

だそうです。

js でも良いのであれば、同記事にやり方も書いてありましたので、ご参考になられると良いと思います。
コピペして動かしてみたところ、下記のようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: user3758624さん。ご回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。